# Convergence of a nonlinear iterative sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fixed-point-theorems

I have the following iterative sequence:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a_{t+1} &=& (1+\alpha-\beta)^2a_{t} - 2\alpha(1+\alpha-\beta)b_{t} +\alpha^2a_{t-1}+\frac{L}{a_{t}}, \\
b_{t+1} &=& (1+\alpha-\beta)a_{t} - \alpha b_{t},
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\alpha, \beta \in (0,1)$, $L>0$, $a_0=b_0=a_1>0$. The question is if $\{(a_t, b_t)\}_{t=1}^{\infty}$ will converge to the fixed point.

By the way, my numerical simulation suggests even the initial value of $a_0, b_0, a_1$ are not equal or positive, the sequence still can converge, so I suspect the initial value doesn't affect the convergence of the sequence.